# Exception running tests "Can not register IUserAppService"

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I'm trying to run the default tests that came with the ABP solution (3.8.1) and I getting the following exception `Abp.AbpException: 'Can not register IUserAppService. It should be a non-abstract class. If not, it should be registered before.'`

We've been working on the project for a couple of months without testing, but we want to be test orientated but I cannot figure out why we are getting this exception.

Here is the constructor for UserAppService so you can see what's injected:

```
public class UserAppService : EEIPFactoriesAppServiceBase
{
    private readonly RoleManager roleManager;
    private readonly IRepository<AppFactory> appFactoryRepository;
    private readonly IPasswordHasher<User> passwordHasher;
    private readonly BackgroundJobManager backgroundJobManager;
    private readonly HostConfiguration hostConfiguration;
    private readonly EmailTemplateManager templateManager;
    private readonly AppFactoryManager appFactoryManager;
    private readonly IRepository<RolePermissionSetting, long> permissionRepository;
    private readonly ISyncHub syncHub;

    public UserAppService(
        UserManager userManager,
        TenantManager tenantManager,
        BackgroundJobManager backgroundJobManager,
        RoleManager roleManager,
        EmailTemplateManager templateManager,
        HostConfiguration hostConfiguration,
        AppFactoryManager appFactoryManager,
        IRepository<RolePermissionSetting, long> permissionRepository,
        IRepository<AppFactory> appFactoryRepository,
        IPasswordHasher<User> passwordHasher,
        ISyncHub syncHub)
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
        TenantManager = tenantManager;
        this.roleManager = roleManager;
        this.backgroundJobManager = backgroundJobManager;
        this.passwordHasher = passwordHasher;
        this.appFactoryRepository = appFactoryRepository;
        this.hostConfiguration = hostConfiguration;
        this.appFactoryManager = appFactoryManager;
        this.templateManager = templateManager;
        this.permissionRepository = permissionRepository;
        this.syncHub = syncHub;
    }
...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make it implement `IUserAppService`.

```cs
public class UserAppService : EEIPFactoriesAppServiceBase, IUserAppService
```